# mongoose: findOne with no result

Tags: mongoose, promise

When the findOne does not have result, the promise is never call.
How do we know that there is no result with Promise

```js
Node.findOne({_id: req.params.nodeId+'x'}).exec().then(function(o){
    console.log(o);
}, function(o){
    console.log(o);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer:
(req.params.nodeId+'x') generate invalid-format id. Thus I received "Cast error".

If I replace it by a valid (but not found) id, I receive null in the call back.